# Problema con old select Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un formulario de consulta con un select, pero luego de hacer el submit, no puedo recuperar el valor old, ya que siempre regresa nulo. Por qué podría suceder eso?

```
<form action="{{ route ('asignaciones.timeline') }}" method="get" 
        class="form-inline float-right ml-3 mt-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ubicacion">Ubicación: </label>
        <select id="ubicacion" name="ubicacion" class="form-control ml-2 mr-2">
            @foreach($ubicaciones as $ubicacion)
            <option value="{{ $ubicacion->id }}" 
                {{ (old('ubicacion') == $ubicacion->id ? 'selected="selected"' : "") }}>
                {{ $ubicacion->ubicacion }}
            </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Buscar</button>
    </div>
    {{ var_dump(old('ubicacion')) }}
</form>
```

**Actualización**

Controlador

```
public function timeline(Request $request) {
   $search = $request->input('ubicacion');

   $asignaciones = Asignacion::orderBy('id')
                    ->ubicacion($search)
                    ->get();

   $ubicaciones = Ubicacion::get();
   return view('asignaciones.timeline', 
         compact('asignaciones', 'ubicaciones'));
}
```

Comment: ¿Está llegando el valor al request y a la validación?

Comment: @Shaz perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

Creo q el error esta en que no definiste una `<option>` fuera del `foreach` con el valor del `old` y tambien en el `value` del `<option>` dentro del `foreach`

Deberias hacer algo como esto

```
<select id="ubicacion" name="ubicacion" class="form-control ml-2 mr-2">
    <option value="{{ $ubicacion->id }}" selected="">{{ $ubicacion->ubicacion }}</option>
         @foreach($ubicaciones as $ubicacion)
            <option value="{{ $ubicacion->id or old('ubicacion') }}" >{{ $ubicacion->ubicacion}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Con el <option> fuera del foreach no reconoce la variable $ubicacion, y si al option fueda del foreach seteo value = {{ old('ubicacion') }} más selected="selected" no funciona.

Comment: publica tu controlador para poder ver que estas mandando para la vista

Comment: En tu metodo create del controller deberias mandar todas las ubicaciones para poder listarlas en el select

Comment: agregué el controlador a la publicación.

Comment: has en la vista enla linea 1 un {{ dd($ubicacion) }} y asegurate que esten llegando los atributos

Comment: @josetuzin lo pudistes resolver¿?